# What is the proper way of securing custom rest api endpoints in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, api, authentication

I am building a Wordpress plugin for my company and most of the work is writing custom rest endpoints. So the flow is like this:

1. User adds his Wordpress website to our admin dashboard which is a separate non-wordpress app.
2. We redirect user to this custom endpoint where user needs to be logged in in order to send us a response that the plugin is installed and this user is truly the owner of this website.

The problem is, when I try to check authentication with permission_callback param, it just doesn't redirect to login page. So, I am trying to manually check it in my method like below:

```
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    auth_redirect();
}
```

But this approache creates a loop. It redirects to login page (with the redirect_url which we sent from our website on the GET param) but when I write down my credentials I just doesn't log in and puts me in a login loop.

Comment: Did you manage to get a solution? I'm trying to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin [DISABLE REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-json-api/)

Comment: No I am not searching for a plugin. I am building one and I can't force customers to install another plugin with mine.